# Return updated session variables (while page is loading) through Ajax call using Django

Tags: ajax, django, django-views, django-sessions

**What I'm trying to do and accomplishing now:**

A user comes to my Django web page to submit a simple form with a couple of input fields that kicks off a complex background process in my background_process view function. I am trying to use session variables so that I can handle multiple users without variables overwriting each other during background processing. Ajax runs during the background processing calling my other view function callback_progress.

callback_progress is updating JSON with variables that are returned to my javascript/jquery ajax through return JsonResponse(data):

```
def callback_progress(request):

    request.session["data"]['numgames'] = request.session["numgames"]
    request.session["data"]['progress'] = request.session["progress"]
    request.session["data"]['win_ratio'] = request.session["win_ratio"]

    response = JsonResponse(request.session["data"])

    return response
```

I can successfully return a JsonResponse from my Ajax call. Here is what my Ajax looks like and what console.log(data) looks like:

**Ajax (simplified a little for readability, I'm updating some html elements in the success block that I removed)**

```
$("#myButton").click(function result_poll() {
        function ajax_call() {
            $.ajax({
                headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
                type : "POST",
                url : "/callback_progress/",
                data: "{{ data }}",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    if (data["progress"] == data["numgames"] && data["progress"] != "0") {
                        clearInterval(interval_id);
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("something went wrong");
                }
            });

        };
        var interval_id = setInterval(ajax_call, 2000);
    });
```

**Console.log output**

```
{numgames: "0", progress: "0", win_ratio: "0"}
{numgames: "0", progress: "0", win_ratio: "0"}
{numgames: "0", progress: "0", win_ratio: "0"}
{numgames: "0", progress: "0", win_ratio: "0"}
{numgames: "0", progress: "0", win_ratio: "0"}
```

**Help me understand:**

**Why are my session variables not returned from the server with their updated values?**

I can see through printing the session variable values that they are updated on my local runserver:

```
{numgames: "5", progress: "1", win_ratio: "0"}
{numgames: "5", progress: "2", win_ratio: "10"}
{numgames: "5", progress: "3", win_ratio: "20"}
{numgames: "5", progress: "4", win_ratio: "30"}
{numgames: "5", progress: "5", win_ratio: "40"}
```

**Here is what I have in settings.py that is relevant from the research I have done:**

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"

SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```

What am I missing here that allows me to return a session variable to the client with updated data while the page is loading?

I'm using Python-3.6 and Django-1.10.6

Comment: In your html-javascript, avoid using the same variable name --data-- in both your json POST and success function.

Comment: @Magnus thank you. Just tested with different names and that doesn't change the result.

Comment: You need to show the code that is supposed to be updating the variables. How is that triggered? Is the session necessarily the appropriate place to store them?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The callback_progress function is in the post... the other session variables like numgames, progress, win_ratio are being set correctly like I said so it wasn't that they weren't being set correctly. I didn't want to overcomplicate the post with too much information from my views. This is about client side calls like ajax getting the up to date values. If they weren't being set correctly I would have shared. I did find a solution that worked for me posted below. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**My engine problem:** I was using the wrong SESSION_ENGINE for what I was trying to accomplish.

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"
```

The signed_cookies session engine does not update the session variables for the client side to see until after an HttpResponse happens (after the page is reloaded/redirected). At least that was my experience.

I updated my session engine to using the db sessions table (which is actually the default according to the [session docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/)):

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.db"
```

**After the engine switch:** I needed to explicitly "save the existing session" to the sessions table so I looked to the save() method documented in [Using Sessions Out of Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views)

```
request.session.save()
```

As info I still used this setting in settings.py to ensure that every request was saving my session objects:

```
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```

Without `request.session.save()` my code did not update the session variables appropriately though.

This is my callback now that ensures the session variables are up to date for my client side ajax call:

```
def callback_progress(request):

    request.session["data"]['numgames'] = request.session["numgames"]
    request.session["data"]['progress'] = request.session["progress"]
    request.session["data"]['win_ratio'] = round(request.session["win_ratio"],2)

    request.session.save()

    response = JsonResponse(request.session["data"])

    return response
```

Comment: Thank you very much for these insights. I am planning to do the same thing and was not sure if it was possible without a page refresh. You probably saved me a lot of time :)